# Resorting id field in database after deleting data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem. I created a database (my_database), created a table inside it(members), and created fields (id, name, lastname, address). The id field is set to auto-increment. Now I have 5 rows, which means id has a value of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. When I  delete id 3, then what's left is '1 2 4 5'. My question is what should I do to resort '1 2 4 5' to '1 2 3 4'? Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: I have to do this resorting because on my site I am displaying all the members using loop and accessing the id number.  Or is it even possible to get the id of a data? Example I have data this data: id=2, lastname=clyde, address=switzerland. How can I get the id value just by the lastname value?

Comment: Do nothing, this is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: You shouldn't be using IDs for _anything_ other than **identifying** a record in the database. Because of this, there's no reason to ever care what pattern a record's ID follows, what order it's in, or anything. **It doesn't matter**, as long as all IDs in a given table are unique (which they will be, with auto_increment).

Comment: Resorting IDs to conform to useless rule of having nice sequential numbers is a huge data integrity hole, not to say major performance killer. Leave it as is, auto_increment isn't supposed to give you sequential numbers that you can use for displaying later on, it has one purpose only and that's to uniquely identify a record.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do that for a number of reasons.

First off, things might go wrong if a page is open. Let's say a user is on the edit page of the entry with `id = 4` when you delete the entry with `id = 3` and update the ids as you suggest. Now, when the editing person hits submit, the id will be taken from his page and he will be updating the new entry 4 instead of the old entry 4. Now this is a blunt and simple example, but beyond those there are lots more things that can go wrong at this level.

Secondly, there is a lot of work involved when programming this. First, you need to update your columns. Then, you also need to make sure MySQL knows what number to give the next entry. And then all of that has to work in an environment that makes sure we don't get quite as many problems with the point mentioned above (which is quite a hard thing). This is a lot of work compared to the alternative of not doing anything.

The third problem is that there is a huge performance overhead. Imagine having a database with thousands upon thousands of entries, and then removing an entry with a low id. Suddenly, all entries with higher ids have to be updated. This might well mean that your site becomes unresponsive because it is doing this task and can't handle too much else at the same time (in fact, in order to make sure that we don't get problems like in the first point, we have to make sure that we don't do anything else at the same time (or make sure we work on different copies of the data or something) because we could end up with a result that comes from during this whole update process.

My suggestion would be in line with what others are saying: just leave it as it is and do not worry about this. `auto_increment` is meant for just one purpose: giving each value a unique identifier easily. Use this identifier to identify and refer to the same entry only. Perhaps one could also make a case about sorting on these identifiers, but no further than to have a certain order (and even then people will disagree with this use of it).

Instead of trying to update the ids, we should look for another place to solve this problem. If the problem is purely how you feel about it, that's easy. You may not feel good about it, but you just need to convince yourself that updating all those ids is not the solution you are looking for. If you use the numbers elsewhere, the problem can be a little more complex to solve. However, there is always the possibility of using PHP to generate numbers for each entry, which most definitely is the logical place to do so if the numbers are used in the generating of your html content. If you provide more details about where you use the sequential numbers, a look could be taken at how to solve it in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know resorting of the id field is not a good  idea. But my site is like this, on my members page I used loop to display all the members in the database. Now when I add a new member it would be automatically displayed, like the list of members is updated and the new entry is there. It works, I already did it. Now my problem is when I delete an entry with id=3, the sequence of the id's is now 1 2 4 5. Thus when i reload the members page slot 3 is empty because it isn't found.

Comment: In response to your iteration issue. after your fetch, don't iterate by ID but iterate over the record set with things like foreach or while, instead of using id field as the index.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what you are doing here. If I'm not mistaken, there is a single page which lists all the members in a single table, right? Now, if a user is deleted, the table will have an empty row, right? Well, if that's what the case is, your strategy for creating the table is not what it should be. I can't tell you how to fix this unless I know how you are doing it right now, but the basic idea is not to run over a set of numbers, but instead over all the rows you receive from the query.

Comment: I am sorry, I'll try to explain again. Yes i have a page which displays all members. I did this by using loop, how? First loop will display first member with id=1, next loop display second member with id=2, until id=5. Now all 5 members are displayed with id 1 2 3 4 5. When I delete member with id=3 from the database, the loop will display only until id=2 coz id=3 is not found anymore. that's why i need to resort all from 1 2 4 5  to  1 2 3 4.

Comment: Yes, then it seems I correctly understood you. Now, you should change the way that page is generated to: the first iteration will display the first result from the query, the second iteration will display the second result from the query, etc.

Comment: how do I do that? pls give me a sample code that displays all members by loop without using the id number.

Comment: `while ($row = $pdo->fetch()) {/* process $row here*/}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do an UPDATE query but mostly developers just leave the id's as is. You can do the numbering in the PHP if it's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either manually update id value by the following statement :

```
update members set id = (id-1) where id > 3;
```

or my advice would be to leave as it is. Its not causing any ambuiguity.